# Memory-efficient random access file writing in C#

Tags: c#, file-writing

So we have a number of files with a custom file-format. These files are then processed to generate a new file based on this content. Think for example processing a .zip file.

The file is being read sequentially and creating some content based on the content.

For instance, reading sequentially could yield the following:

- 1st Byte: 'S' at index #0 = 'S'
- 2nd Byte: 'U' at index #0 = 'US'
- 3rd Byte: 'C' at index #0 = 'CUS'
- 4th Byte: 'B' at index #0 = 'BCUS'
- 5th Byte: 'A' at index #0 and index #2 = 'ABACUS'

A few points worth noting about this:

- The file contents tend to start off from the end of the resultant file leading to the start - however this is not always the case.
- Reading the file backwards - I think - is not an option since this would then mess up the indexes
- The resultant file length cannot be determined beforehand - unless the entire content of the file is read and parsed
- Indexes can potentially span through the entire range of the file.
- It cannot be known beforehand that there are empty spaces in-between bytes for instances between *B* and *C* in *BCUS* which is later filled up as *ABACUS*.

Currently I'm writing the resultant content in an in-memory `List<byte>;` and then writing the results to file. This is not ideal since it means that the whole resultant file is loaded in-memory.

I have did a bit of checking and found MemoryMapping in C# which seemed like a great idea at first glance however from what I've seen 1) it requires knowing the file-length beforehand and 2) it has no support for inserting bytes at specified indexes - whilst pushing any existent content to adjacent bytes.

I was also thinking of storing bits of the data (as chunks) for instance every 1MB of file content as a separate file while processing. However due to the random access nature of the writes and possibly spanning the entire length of the file, I think there would be a lot of file I/O in terms of opening / closing files and re-reading their data.

Do you have any ideas of how this can be performed efficiently?

Comment: From  what I read from your approach you don't really have a choice but saving it into the memory before processing it? Maybe you could use structs to keep it in the heap, but to know more, the algorithm should be a bit more clear, and I guess that's the part that you cannot really share?

Comment: You will have to make some compromise. It's very unlikely that you will find a solution that is both fast and memory-efficient, given the randomness of the data. Either you go for speed, and handling an array of byte (or some kind of linked-list of chunks) is a good approach, or you go for memory efficiency and you can probably work something out by processing each file in multiple passes instead of trying to do everything in one go (basically, you can do one pass to compute the size of the resulting file, then allocate it on the disk, and do a second pass to fill it)

Comment: A C# program, like any program, only ever reads and writes file data from/to RAM.  It never interacts directly with the disk, only with the file system cache.  It is the OS duty to keep data in the cache up to date and in sync.  Might cause a delay when reading if it is not yet in the cache, won't delay writing.  Modern machines easily have 4 gigabytes of cache.  That makes micro-optimizing file related code a lost cause in most cases, you just can't see any improvement.  The only way to be sure is to try it.

Comment: If file is being read sequentially then use BinaryReader.

Comment: @jdweng - the source file is being read sequentially and I've already taken measures to retain as little a memory-footprint as possible, however the issue is mainly with the file being written as a result, rather then the source file.

Comment: @HansPassant - valid point that you are not really interacting with the file itself... regarding the rest, not sure I understand correctly but are you suggesting that writing the resultant file all in-memory (as a List of bytes) a good approach?

Comment: Not what I suggested, I can't really guess how you drew that conclusion.  You in effect have it in memory twice.  Once in your program's memory, again in the file system cache.  Not a good use of RAM.  Only optimize disk usage when you have good evidence that the disk is the actual bottleneck.  Only a profiler can show you that.